# Stuck on installing Ubuntu 19.10 on pi with "reached target cloud-init target" as last message

Tags: password, raspberrypi, 19.10

I'm on a Raspberry Pi 4B and I'm trying to install the Ubuntu supported 19.10 image. However, it doesn't let me type in a password (at least the cursor doesn't move so it doesn't seem as if I'm typing anything).

I saw somewhere that the password should be `ubuntu`. After it waits a couple of seconds it continues for some time and then it reaches 2 `[OK]` lines:

```
[OK] "Start Execute cloud user/final scripts"
[OK] "Reached target cloud-init target"
```

After that, it stops and I have to do a hard shut down.

If I try a second time, there's all kind of gibberish that follows on the enter login line. And it stops a little earlier.

What I'm (still) expecting is a desktop environment to open up.

And as for the password, whether I enter it or not it doesn't seem to matter because it produces the same lines of messages and stops.

Comment: 19.10 is pretty new, and not a LTS version, it could be easier if you wait 20.04 or use 18.04; I don't think that would be a good thing to update a Raspberry Pi each 6-9 months

Comment: It's normal that you don't see a cursor move as you enter your password. See [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password), which applies to entering a password to log in on a virtual console (even though the example given in the question is a `sudo` password prompt).

Comment: I edited my message. Perhaps I'm just expecting the wrong thing and this image is meant for different use. But together with not responding to anything at all at the very end it doesn't seem like it's doing the right thing. I kind of gave up now and will perhaps follow up on damadam's comment. But if there are any other comments or solutions it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Same here. Didn't get it to work. The 32-bit version boots fine, but I had random crashes and didn't get bluetooth and 3D video drivers to work (some screens take a lot of time to render) However, it seems the partial solution to USB problem is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182369/ubuntu-19-10-has-no-working-keyboard-or-mouse-for-raspberry-pi-4-model-b-only-w/1182372#1182372

Comment: ironically, if i hit a key to login at this point, and then do a safe shutdown, when it reboots it completes the boot

Answer (score 2):

I arrived here with a different context
I install ubuntu server 20.04 in a virtualbox

I agree with the comments saying its not stuck but waiting for the login

Comment: +1 but it wasn't obvious. Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS installed on a home server: as per the OP it seemed that the server had "hung" during boot as I was expecting to be given a logon prompt. All I had to do was to hit Enter and the logon prompt appeared.