# Ubuntu 19.10 on RaspberryPi 4 hangs on first boot

Tags: boot, raspberrypi

Burned ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz. First boot on RaspberryPi 4 looked ok until it hung after

```
[ OK ] Reached target Cloud-init target.
```

Power cycled, and boot ended with

```
Ubuntu 19.10 ubuntu tty
Ubuntu login: [  23.431015] cloud-init…
[...] cloud-init…
```

Then no response to keyboard input, in USB2 or 3 port. The same procedure worked fine (successful login, etc) on first boot with a RaspberryPi 3.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182369/ubuntu-19-10-has-no-working-keyboard-or-mouse-for-raspberry-pi-4-model-b-only-w worked for me. Had to ssh via wired.

Answer (score 1):

Set total_mem=3072 in /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt
(If you mount the sd card in another computer, the usercfg.txt is on the small vfat partition.)

Comment: It’s /volumes/system-boot/usercfg.txt, not /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt, on my mac.
Added total_mem=3072 and it works. (This is a new setting, not overriding one in config.txt.) Many thanks!